# Accept null values client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using below code i identify loggedIn users location.
But some users doesn't have locations
ex:Administrator is common for all locations then how can i set if value comes as a null
then it need to show location is ALL.

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"].ToString()
```

Comment: Try @(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"] ?? "ALL").ToString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the following expression...

```
@(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"] != null
    ? HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"].ToString()
    : "ALL")
```

but really, try to change your approach...keeping user's information in session state is horrible and not scalable

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,a more shorter version of **@Leo's** answer :-

```
@((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"] ?? "ALL")
```

Comment: make sure you convert that expression to string otherwise the session object will return a `System.Object` instance rather than a string...`@(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"] ?? "ALL").ToString()`

Comment: oops, true, I just copied/pasted without even checking...+1

Comment: @Leo...no problem..:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know session state handling, but maybe this works?

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"]) && userIsAdministrator)
{
    @HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"] = "ALL";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The shortest way to achieve that is probably with the [`null-coalescing operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) :

```
string userLocation = @((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLocation"] ?? "ALL");
```

The behavior is pretty simple; when the left side is null, it returns what you specify on the right side. If the left side is non-null, it returns the left side.

You also need a cast to `string` since `Session` returns the base type `object`.

Comment: @Kartikeya And which part of it is wrong? It compiles fine. It is your version that is lacking a cast to string, can't mix object and string types.

Comment: just copy and paste your code and place it in visual studio and you will come to know...

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault this will cause a compilation error in razor

Comment: @Leo Pretty weird, but it's fine on my side. Kartikeya version does not compile at all however. Oh well.

Comment: My answer is not compiling...well..i think you are mistaken my friend...or you are not understanding question correctly.......

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault probably razor is getting confused and very likely interpreting that as encoded html by exposing the coding internals to the client browser. The fact is, you're not properly switching to a code block expression in razor

Comment: @Leo Yeah may be Razor getting confused. Anyway; null-coalescing or ternary operator to solve the original problem. Let's stop extending the discussion in the comment section, we'll likely get a warning to go to chat.

Comment: before your answer there were answer here which were using ternary operator and null-coalescing ... so there is no new thing in this answer and plz correct the answer which should work fine because it's a asp.net mvc tagged question...there is no shame in correcting the wrong answer.....